# Catalyst::Controller::Rest callback serializer not working

Tags: perl, catalyst

I need to return different content types from a REST controller I have the following configuration:

```
__PACKAGE__->config(
default => 'application/json',
'stash_key' => 'rest',
map => {
    'text/html' => [ 'Callback', { deserialize => \&parse_html, serialize => \&render_html } ],
    'text/xml'  => [ 'Callback', { deserialize => \&parse_xml, serialize => \&render_xml } ],
    'text/csv'  => [ 'Callback', { deserialize => \&parse_csv, serialize => \&render_csv } ] } );
```

I've made some tests first setting an Accept header from the client:

```
$ua->post($url, Accept => "text/csv", Content=>$args)
```

Then I've tried to force it in the server:

```
$c->resp->content_type("test/csv")
```

But either of this returns a 415 unsupported media type, am I missing something here?